# Import failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, sqoop

When migrating a table from postgres to hdfs (hive) using sqoop api java, an error occurs. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your program within your IDE, when it starts, it can't find `hive` on the PATH. I presume you're using IntelliJ, therefore you need to check your Launch Configuration and if you just executed in Debug mode or Run mode:

I would expect something like the following is being executed and is missing the `cd` or the PATH to your `hive` binary:

```
cd $HIVE_SRC/packaging/target/apache-hive-{version}-bin/apache-hive-{version}-bin
bin/hive --debug -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

Comment: Thanks, my java app is outside hadoop cluster. Hadoop runs in docker container (image Cloudera).

Comment: So, how can your java app access the `hive` binary then ? Maybe is helpful to provide some of the architectural decisions, then, together with the `.pom` snippet that you consider relevant, to understand the issue. Maybe you need to install hive on your laptop/desktop.